# Reactjs - on the fly search results

Tags: javascript, search

I've created a filter/sort module that will allow the user to type in the name of a company -- and it will create the api query string to do the search on the fly.

However, if the user types too fast -- the calls would stack or come too late to be relevant to the user's search. How do I improve the search to get the very latest parameters -- when I set the state for these filters/orderby - there is already a delay

itemsReady -- is a boolean to toggle on a spinner/show results

```
  filterResults(configuration){
    let that = this;

    this.setState({
      filterBy: configuration.filterBy,
      orderBy: configuration.orderBy,
    });

    this.setState({
      itemsReady: false,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      that.runSearch();
    }, 1);
  }



  runSearch(){

    let that = this;

    let params = {
      "pageSize": this.state.pageSize,
      "pageNumber": this.state.pageNumber,
      "orderBy": this.state.orderBy,
      "filterBy": this.state.filterBy
    }

    this.props.fetchFullSearch(this.state.serviceCategoryId, JSON.stringify(this.state.termsData), params, function(resp){
      if(resp && resp.status===200){
  
        that.setState({
          searchtermresults: resp,
          pageCount: Math.ceil(resp.data.count/that.state.pageSize),
          isSearching: false,
        });
    
        let accountType = "guest";

        if(isLogged()){
          if(isBuyer()){
            accountType = "buyer";
          }
          if(isPartner()){
            accountType = "partner";
          }
        }

        that.buildResultList(accountType);


      }else{
        //error has occured - show error snackbar
      }
    });
  }
```

---

I've tried to set flags -- if isSearching -- or oldFilterBy - last state --- and to try and run the search again - the last resort here is to place a submit button to action the filter, but the onfly search is good otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling out search event using debounce concept so that it fetches your strings correctly when the user has done typing or taken a pause.  https://medium.com/walkme-engineering/debounce-and-throttle-in-real-life-scenarios-1cc7e2e38c68

Comment: you mean - on the callback of the search - check to see if it compares to the current filter states - and if not -- run a search again?

Comment: you mean -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce  - install this -- and wrap the runSearch around that debounce()

Comment: I've tried to install this -- and wrap it around the search  - but its like it never gets triggered?         that.timer = setTimeout(() => {

        debounce(100, () => {
          that.runSearch();
        });

      }, 1);

Comment: -- what I've done - is added a debounce -- which I think helps stop making a bunch of calls in miliseconds --- and if the data has changed during a search -- do a late search about 1.5 seconds again just to catch --- cause searching for a company with b -- and then be -- the first search takes longer to get results back.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` returns a handle that you can later use to cancel its function call by calling `clearTimeout`. Typically, this kind of trigger while the user is typing is done like so:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', _e => {
  const searchField = document.querySelector('#search-field');
  let searchTo;
  searchField.addEventListener('input', e => {
    //That's what you need to do
    if (searchTo)
      clearTimeout(searchTo);
    searchTo = setTimeout(doMySearch, 300); //<-- adjust this delay to your needs
  });
  
  function doMySearch() { //This implementation is meaningless. It's just for you to see what's happening
    searchTo = undefined;
    document.querySelector(".searches").innerText += `\n"${searchField.value}"`
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="search-field">Search here</label>
<input type="search" id="search-field" />
<h5>Searches:</h5>
<pre class="searches">

</pre>
```

Comment: the site here is pretty complicated with a nested form framework -- the typing in your company name is only one of several fields - but its the most noticeable issue as a person can really mash the keyboard fast than check checkboxes fast

Comment: If your problem, as I understood, is searches being triggered repeatidly due to keyboard mashing, then this logic applies, no matter what the details of input / output are. I can see in your code that you're already using `setTimeout` to call `runSearch`. Then clear it and set it again when a new event occurs

Comment: I've got a setTimeout on the runsearch - because it takes a little time for react to set states

Comment: its more like filterResults will get invoked again -- if new data comes - maybe I will try a clearTimeout there at the top and see if it jogs it